# Image binding, changed image step by step

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have create a poker application. I have 6 players, 2 cards per player. I would like to know how can I illustrate the deal. I changed the picture with the card at the deal, then step by step. But the cards picture doesn't changed. If I do it in `syncrhon` the card picture will change after the iteration. If I use the `asynchron` mode, the card picture doeesn't changed.
Thank you your help.

There is the code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < opposers.Count; i++)
                {
                //    View.View.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                //    {
                        if (j == 0)
                            GetPlayer(i).Card1 = new Card(deck.Pop());
                        else GetPlayer(i).Card2 = new Card(deck.Pop());
                    //Thread.Sleep(500);
                    //});
                }
            }


      <Image Width="50" Height="80" Source="{Binding Card2.ImgCard}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Canvas.Left="108.358" Canvas.Top="-8.349">
                    <Image.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform Rotation="16.39" SkewY="1.788" ScaleY="0.995" ScaleX="1.005" />
                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                </Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good by using binding. I would recommend to use Storyboard instead of Threading Sleep but that is not the question here.

You need to make sure that your `ImgCard` property really does raise the [PropertyChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx).
Then you need to setup your code by updating the Image as `new ImageSource` and set new imagesource to the property that the event will raise.

`

```
Public Shared ReadOnly IsSpinningProperty As DependencyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsSpinning",
                                GetType(Boolean),
                                GetType(MyCode))

Public Property IsSpinning() As Boolean
    Get
        Return CBool(GetValue(IsSpinningProperty))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        SetValue(IsSpinningProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

`
now, you can change the value IsSpinning by codebehind like

```
IsSpinning = NOT IsSpinning 'simple swtich the value
```

If IsSpinning will now switch it will use the SetValue methode and this methode will raise an event to all items which are bind to this IsSpinnning property.

Comment: thank you Nasenbaer, It's new for me yet, but I will see it how Does It work

Comment: Please answer C# questions with C# examples if you can :)

Comment: HiTech Magic: I will try. I just need to convert to C# in the current case and did not trust the converter. :-)